# Cedar-14 bundle fails: Could not load OpenSSL

Tags: ruby, heroku, openssl, bundler

I'm upgrading a production app on Heroku to Cedar-14. I forked my staging app `heroku fork -a v-upgrade v-upgrade2`, verified that the forked version was up and running on Cedar-10, set the stack to Cedar-14, created a dummy commit, and upon pushing received the following:

```
~/documents/coding/cycling/velopro$ git push upgrade2 currentdev:master
Counting objects: 11833, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7014/7014), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11833/11833), 91.20 MiB | 1.05 MiB/s, done.
Total 11833 (delta 8521), reused 6407 (delta 4535)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.0
remote: -----> Installing gsl
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Could not load OpenSSL.
remote:        You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
remote:        Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using
remote:        RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.
remote:        Bundler Output:
remote:        Could not load OpenSSL.
remote:        You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
remote:        Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using
remote:        RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to v-upgrade2.
remote: 
To git@heroku.com:v-upgrade2.git
 ! [remote rejected] currentdev -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:v-upgrade2.git'
```

I reconfirmed that I could still push to the original staging app (v-upgrade) on Heroku without issue, so the only difference between them appears to be the Cedar stack.

Has anyone else encountered a bundler issue loading OpenSSL on Cedar-14? Is there a way to "recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support" on Heroku?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I punted. The buildpack I was using hadn't been updated in a while so instead of attempting to fix it, I simply forked `heroku-buildpack-ruby` and added a few lines of code to include the GSL library that I needed as follows:

**/Rakefile**

```
+  GSL_VENDOR_URL   = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/gsl_bin/gsl-1.15.tgz"
```

**/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb**

```
 class LanguagePack::Ruby < LanguagePack::Base
+  GSL_VENDOR_URL       = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/gsl_bin/gsl-1.15.tgz"
   NAME                 = "ruby"
   LIBYAML_VERSION      = "0.1.6"
   LIBYAML_PATH         = "libyaml-#{LIBYAML_VERSION}"
@@ -57,7 +58,8 @@ class LanguagePack::Ruby < LanguagePack::Base
   def default_config_vars
     instrument "ruby.default_config_vars" do
       vars = {
-        "LANG" => env("LANG") || "en_US.UTF-8"
+        "LANG" => env("LANG") || "en_US.UTF-8",
+        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" => ld_path,
       }

       ruby_version.jruby? ? vars.merge({
@@ -88,6 +90,9 @@ class LanguagePack::Ruby < LanguagePack::Base
       setup_export
       setup_profiled
       allow_git do
+        install_gsl
+        run("cp -R vendor/gsl-1 /app/vendor/gsl")
+        run("cp -R vendor/gsl-1 /app/vendor/gsl-1")
         install_bundler_in_app
         build_bundler
         post_bundler
@@ -111,6 +116,7 @@ private
     paths         = [
       ENV["PATH"],
       "bin",
+      "/app/vendor/gsl-1/bin",
       system_paths,
     ]
     paths.unshift("#{slug_vendor_jvm}/bin") if ruby_version.jruby?
@@ -119,6 +125,10 @@ private
     paths.join(":")
   end

+  def ld_path
+    "/app/vendor/gsl-1/lib"
+  end
+
   def binstubs_relative_paths
     [
       "bin",
@@ -459,6 +469,15 @@ ERROR
     FileUtils.rm File.join('bin', File.basename(path)), :force => true
   end

+  def install_gsl
+    topic("Installing gsl")
+    bin_dir = "vendor/gsl-1"
+    FileUtils.mkdir_p bin_dir
+    Dir.chdir(bin_dir) do |dir|
+      run("curl #{GSL_VENDOR_URL} -s -o - | tar xzf -")
+    end
+  end
```

In the end, while it may not have been as emotionally satisfying to figure out what was wrong with loading OpenSSL, this is probably the better route anyway.